# reform dataframe from sample results

Tags: pandas

I have a random sampled table --df1. I want to use the "product_class" and "id" in df1 to map the samle columns in my original df and extract all columns from df that match the "product_class" and "id" in df1.

How do I do it?

```
 df

      product_class   sample_id   price   region
 0     pc1              1          45      1
 1     pc1              2          51      2 
 2     pc1              3          52      9
 3     pc1              4          47      3
 4     pc1              5          48      7
 5     pc2              1          65      6
 6     pc2              2          64      4 
 7     pc2              3          52      9
 8     pc2              4          47      3
 9     pc2              5          48      7


df 1

    product_class    sample_id
 0    pc1             [3,4]
 1    pc2             [3,5]  


new_df
     product_class   sample_id   price   region
 0     pc1              3          52      9
 1     pc1              4          47      3
 2     pc2              3          52      9
 3     pc2              5          48      7
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `explode` and `merge`

```
df2 = df1.explode('sample_id').merge(df)

Out[95]:
  product_class sample_id  price  region
0           pc1         3     52       9
1           pc1         4     47       3
2           pc2         3     52       9
3           pc2         5     48       7
```